# The diamond operator seems to work only once

Tags: perl, while-loop

I am writing a script in Perl where I have to open the same file twice in my code. This is my outline of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %forward=();
my %reverse=();

while(<>){
    chomp;
    # store something
    }   
}

while(<>){ # open the same file again
    chomp;
    #print something
}
```

I am using the diamond operator so I am running the script like this

```
perl script.pl input.txt
```

But this is not producing any output. If I open the File using filehandle, the script works. What can be possibly wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

Save your `@ARGV` before exhausting it. Of course, this will only work for actual files specified on the command line, and not with `STDIN`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

run(@ARGV);

sub run {
    my @argv = @_;
    first(@argv);
    second(@argv);
}

sub first {
    local @ARGV = @_;
    print "First pass: $_" while <>;
}

sub second {
    local @ARGV = @_;
    print "Second pass: $_" while <>;
}
```

Comment: Hi Sinan, I am unable to understand this thing. Do I have to paste my code where your while(<>) thing is. Can you explain??

Comment: @user3138373 Copy and paste his script into an editor and save it as `read_file_twice.pl`. Then run as `perl read_file_twice.pl input.txt`

Answer (score 3):

You read all there was to be read in the first loop, leaving nothing to read in the second.

If the input aren't huge, you can simply load it into memory.

```
my @lines = <>;
chomp( @lines );

for (@lines) {
   ...
}

for (@lines) {
   ...
}
```